# Entity Framework EF Core exception "Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I use EFCore 5.0.12

I have the following Entity:

```
public class Course {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public CourseLevel Level { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(7,2)")]
    public decimal FullPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Now I try to do a group-query like:

```
var query3 =
   from c in context.Courses
   group c by c.Level
   into g
   select g;
foreach (var group in query3) {
   Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key} ({group.Count()})");

   foreach (var c in group) {
       Console.WriteLine($"\t{c.Title}");
   }
}
```

This generates the Exception

> Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable'
> before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side.

Why can this not be translated to sql?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239258/discussion-on-question-by-bennodual-entity-framework-ef-core-exception-unable-t).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database simply can't produce a result that is produced by a plain LINQ `GroupBy`.
Both, database and LINQ use a different form of grouping.
Opposed to LINQ grouping, databases have stricter rules: grouping **must** always be used with an aggregation function like `Count()`, `Sum()`, `Avg()`, `Min()` or `Max()`.

**Example**
Given is the following table

```
Users
-------------------------
| age | name  | lastname |
-------------------------
| 27  | Nancy | Doe
| 27  | Nancy | Apple
| 65  | Bob   | Uncle
| 27  | Bob   | Doe
| 35  | Bob   | Marley
| 27  | Jim   | Beam
--------------------------
```

A common LINQ query would be:

*"Get all `Users` records grouped by `age`".*

```
Users.GroupBy(user => user.Age);
```

Result is a set of tupels where the `key` is the `age` and the `value` a collection of `User` instances where `User.Age` is equaL `(key, {...})`:

```
(27, {User, User, User, User})
(65, {User})
(35, {User})
```

The above result shows the limitations of database grouping: it is not possible to make a database return such a result. A database can't return lists or arrays - it only returns rows and columns. Therefore, such a query can't be translated to SQL or executed by a database, hence EF throws an exception to notify the client about this inconvenience.
The solution to this problem would be to explicitly execute the grouping on the client-side, outside the database context, or to fix the expression to meet the aforementioned rules for valid database grouping.

A valid SQL query would be:

*"Get the number of users that are of `age` '27' grouped by `name`."*

```
SELECT Count(age), name FROM Users WHERE age=27 GROUP BY name
```

Result is a set of tuples, where the `key` is the `count` of users with the same age and the `value` the `name` of those users `(age_count, name)`:

```
(2, Nancy)
(1, Bob)
(1, Jim)
```

If the LINQ query uses an aggregation function too, the query can be translated to SQL without any problems.
To produce the above result of the SQL query we can write:

```
dbContext.Users
  .GroupBy(
    user => user.Name, 
    (name, users) => new { Count = users.Count(user => user.Age == 27), name });
```

Or

```
from user in dbContext.Users
group user by user.Name
into groups 
select new { Count = groups.Count(user => user.Age == 27), groups.Key };
```

Comment: I thought that our discussion above pretty well settled that EF doesn't depend on what a database query returns. If that were true there wouldn't be O/R mappers.

Comment: @GertArnold EF is a multi-purpose framework. Aside from imlementing an ORM framework it also acts as wrapper/adapter for the actual database. In context of wrapping the database it must also translate C# language queries to corresponding database queries (especially if we want the query to execute 100% server-side for max performance). Otherwise you would have to write database queries directly from your code (like when using ADO .NET). In the context of the database wrapping/adapter, EF must produce a valid database query and in return gets a classic database query result (rows and columns).

Comment: @GertArnold The ORM context kicks in always on the client-side as this is the required language context for the data types that the result is mapped to. EF implements multiple concepts or abstraction models. Those model boundaries get blurred (what is the idea behind a framework like EF - in order to add convenience, it must operate on an abstract projections of the underlying system). It virtually merges all the different contexts. But in reality you have a database connector, adapter and ORM component.

Comment: @GertArnold The abstraction is largely dictaded by the C# language programming model. The idea is to extent the C# language experience into the database context to help non database devs to interact with the database. You don't have to learn e.g. SQL. Just treat the database as an object or data type. So don't confuse what EF does with what a database does.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly loop over an `IGrouping` (if you are building an `IQueryable` of course), the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby) explains that:

> Furthermore, `IGrouping` implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`, which means you can compose over it using any LINQ operator after the grouping. **Since no database structure can represent an `IGrouping`, `GroupBy` operators have no translation in most cases**. When an aggregate operator is applied to each group, which returns a scalar, it can be translated to SQL `GROUP BY` in relational databases.

Comment: As I said above, this is more about implementation decisions than anything else. It's not impossible at all to compose over group-by. As the old EF6 did it, it was nothing but sorting by the grouping key and creating the grouping afterwards in memory. The SQL statement didn't even contain a GROUP BY clause. (Unless, of course, only a group aggregate was queried).

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to some of the other comments, the problem seems to merely be in the translation of the group to something returnable as a query

To that end

For a starting point of

```cs
queryable
  .GroupBy(...)
```

the correction is

```cs
  .Select(group => group.Select(member => ...))
```

to create the transform of how any member of the group should be represented

I don't know how to best represent this in the query syntax, but the point about `GroupBy` not having a translation seems to fail to then follow up with that you can solve it by translating the result